# Django error: User matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So I have these models in my Django project, and I am trying to get the `user2` variable or the other user of my models

```py
class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs

    def get_or_new(self, user, other_username): # get_or_create
        username = user.username
        if username == other_username:
            return None
        qlookup1 = Q(first__username=username) & Q(second__username=other_username)
        qlookup2 = Q(first__username=other_username) & Q(second__username=username)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2).distinct()
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first(), False
        elif qs.count() > 1:
            return qs.order_by('timestamp').first(), False
        else:
            Klass = user.__class__
            user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            if user != user2:
                obj = self.model(first=user, second=user2)
                obj.save()
                return obj, True
            return None, False


class Thread(models.Model):
    first = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ThreadManager()
```

and my views

```py
def Messages(request, *args, **kwargs):
    Chats = Thread.objects.by_user(request.user)
    other_username = kwargs.get("username")
    other_user = Thread.objects.get_or_new(request.user, other_username)
    context = {
        'content': Chats,
        'chatname': other_user
    }
    return render(request, "chat/messages.html", context)
```

But when I try to get the other user I get the title error. Does anybody know what is going on?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Above `user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)` add `print(other_username`) to diagnose

Comment: @GAEfan I did what you tell me and it prints the other username, but what is the point of that

Comment: The point is to check that you are querying for what you think you are querying.  Same spelling, capitalization, no spaces, etc.  And does a user with that exact spelling exist in `Klass` (`User`)?

Comment: @GAEfan So is that the solution of my problem?

Comment: I do not know.  What is the value of `other_username` right before the query?  And does a User of that username exist in the database?

Comment: you need to debug your code, that what the `print()` solution are for. Check what value are variable passing in your query by checking the console when it print out

Comment: @LinhNguyen yes I did it and it print it out the the thing I just need, the problem is that I need to query that in my views

Comment: have you tried running that query in `manage.py shell` with mock data yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your models, it seems that user2 variable is the second object, to get the second object you need to use only the content context you made, and loop for it in your template {% for chat in content %} {{ chat.second }} this will give you the second user that is not your user of all your objects